# Chrome extension "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')"

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, google-chrome-extension

[image]So I'm trying to create a chrome extension that allows to download any image from website, but I'm a newbie to the js and web development, so here is the problem:

I partially understand my code but it seems that it must be something like this:

**content-script.js**

```
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "downloadMedia",
    title: "Download Image",
    contexts: ["image"],
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === "downloadImage") {
    const imageUrl = request.imageUrl;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "downloadImage", imageUrl: imageUrl });
  }
});

// Send a message to the background script to initiate the download
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "downloadImage", imageUrl: imageUrl }, (response) => {
  if (response && response.downloadId) {
    console.log(`Download initiated with ID: ${response.downloadId}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Download failed.");
  }
});
```

**background.js**

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === "downloadImage") {
    const imageUrl = request.imageUrl;
    downloadImage(imageUrl);
    return true;
  }
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId === "downloadMedia") {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: (info) => {
        const imageUrl = info.srcUrl;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "downloadImage", imageUrl: imageUrl });
      },
      args: [info],
    });
  }
});

function downloadImage(imageUrl, sendResponse) {
  chrome.downloads.download({ url: imageUrl }, (downloadId) => {
    // The download is complete,send a response
    sendResponse({ downloadId });
  });
}
```

**parts of manifest.json**

```
...
 "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "downloads",
    "contextMenus",
    "runtime"
  ],
...
 "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["/scripts/content-script.js"]
    }
  ]
...
```

the option doesn't show up in the context menu, also in the debug i always see this error on the very first line of content-js:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')**

**updated background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === "downloadImage") {
    const imageUrl = request.imageUrl;
    downloadImage(imageUrl);
    return true;
  }
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Download Image",
  contexts: ["image"],
  id: "downloadImage",
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId === "downloadImage") {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: (info) => {
        const imageUrl = info.srcUrl;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "downloadImage", imageUrl: imageUrl });
      },
      args: [info],
    });
  }
});

function downloadImage(imageUrl, sendResponse) {
  chrome.downloads.download({ url: imageUrl }, (downloadId) => {
    // The download is complete, send a response
    sendResponse({ downloadId });
  });
}
```

**updated content-script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === "downloadImage") {
    const imageUrl = request.imageUrl;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "downloadImage", imageUrl: imageUrl });
  }
});
```

Comment: Remove everything except chrome.runtime.onMessage section from your content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm that resolved error but there still no 'download image' in context menu :(

Comment: Well, move the first section from your old content script into the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm xd, it did help, but there is now two buttons of 'download image' that not doing anything, i'll try to figure out, appreciate your help

Comment: chrome.contextMenus.create should be inside onInstalled callback and you can call chrome.contextMenus.removeAll() first.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything except chrome.runtime.onMessage section from your content script. –
wOxxOm

that resolved error but there still no 'download image' in context menu

Well, move the first section from your old content script into the background script. –
wOxxOm